# Why did Anakin get the title Darth?

Tags: star-wars, sith, darth-vader, names

In "*Darth Bane Path of Destruction*" one of the instructors said `"The Darth title was more than just a symbol of power; it was a claim of supremacy. It was used by those Dark Lords who have sought to enforce their will on the other Masters. It was a challenge — a warning to bow down or be destroyed."`

So if the title Darth is reserved only for those strong enough to claim supremacy why did the Emperor just grant his apprentice this title? It seems completely out of character, for him and Sith in general, to grant his apprentice such an undeserved elevation.

Comment: Good question. It seems from your quote a Sith can only claim the title of Darth for himself, as opposed to being granted the title, since it effectively acts as a challenge/threat to other Sith. Maybe the movie canon overrides the work you're quoting?

Comment: @AndresF. - G canon always trumps C canon. Well, almost.

Comment: It's really not that much out of character. If he's a Darth and has another Darth bow down to him, what does it say about him? The logical assumption is that as his master, he must be even more powerful. Besides, he was about to claim the title of Emperor. So of course his apprentice and right hand needed a powerful title as well. Also, Palpatine/Sidious might have seen it more as a historic title for accomplished Sith and not really a claim for supremacy. His previous apprentices had the title of Darth too. Like Maul.

Comment: How is this different from Darth Maul? Didn't he take his orders from the Emperor too? or was it the Chancellor at that time...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question is kind of subjective. "undeserved" how? How do you "deserve" it?

By  being among the most powerful Sith in the galaxy? Check... only the Emperor was more powerful (being that there were only 2 left).

By getting there via murdering the OTHER Sith contender in combat? Check. Scratch one Lord Tyrannus.

By ruthlessly exterminating enemies, including Jedi? Check. Scratch the whole Jedi Temple of them. (Obi-Wan being the sole exception).

By being a famous warrior? Check, even as a Jedi during Clone Wars.

---

Also, remember that he wasn't **named** Darth from the get-go-whiny-Anakin-NOOOOOOOOOO!!!! moment. When he awoke, Sidious merely called him "Lord Vader":

> DARTH SIDIOUS: (continuing) Lord Vader, can you hear me? ([src](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Revenge-of-the-Sith.html))

After that, he cleaned up a bunch of OTHER Jedi who escaped Order 66.

Comment: Actually right after they killed Windoo he gave Anakin his new name and called him Darth Vadar

Comment: From [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Revenge-of-the-Sith.html): "
PALPATINE: Good. Good. The Force is strong with you. A powerful Sith you will become. Henceforth, you shall be known as Darth . . . Vader. "

Comment: There can't be more than two Sith at the same time according to the [rule of two](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rule_of_Two)

Comment: @MaëlNison Not that they particularly respected said rule, as shown in the Expanded Universe :P

Comment: Mara Jade is a testament to that.

Comment: @TheLollipopGuildmaster - Mara Jade was the Hand. She wasn't even Dark Jedi, never mind a Sith.

Answer (score 3):

Just a note, even in the Darth Bane series (which I just finished yesterday, so pretty fresh), When Bane takes Rain as his apprentice, he gives her the title of Darth then and there. The same applies to taking

> the Huntress as an apprentice, Darth Cognus.

So it seems that following the Rule of Two leads to a Master and Apprentice, both worthy of the title Darth.

Answer (score 2):

Every Sith apprentice is granted the title of Darth after the rule of two was installed by Darth Bane.

Comment: Any citation or reference to back that up ?

Comment: @Stan Check at this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sith) under the Notable sith Lords for the citation :)

Comment: @AjoKoshy -that list doesn't include **every sith apprentice**

Comment: @Ajo Koshy My comment was directed to the answerer.  A short, single statement answer is provided with absolutely no citations or backing references.  If leo thinks that's the answer, should be able to provide some justification for it.

Answer (score 0):

Anakin was stronger than Dooku (witness Palpatine's "soon I will have a new apprentice, younger and more powerful"), and Dooku was Darth Tyranus. Hence Anakin must be a Darth.

True, it was just Palpatine's opinion, but in this case he was the one doing the naming so his opinion happens to matter a lot (notice that he has no hesitation over "Darth" but does over "Vader").